# export quality images from Paraview

Tags: vtk, paraview

I would like to export quality vector graphics from paraview however all the vector graphics formats exported seem to be a bit blurry except svg(svg is also not perfect but better that ps and eps). Are there any workarounds for this problem that I can get publication quality images?

Comment: I guess you are aware of this blog post http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/508 ?

Answer (score 6):

The vector graphics output only affects the non-3D rendered elements such as texts, cube axes etc. (as discussed on in this post: http://www.kitware.com/blog/home/post/508). If you are referring to the blurriness of the 3D rendered scene itself, you may want to try saving higher resolution pngs instead.

Comment: As a side node, vector graphics support has been temporarily removed in 5.0.0 release. We are working on bringing it back.